# Select-string patern match and notmatch

Tags: powershell, design-patterns, select-string

I am fairly new to Powershell and have run into a bit of a pickle.

I'm trying to find string "o_dwh" in scripts, but if there is exec before this statement like this - "exec o_dwh" - I don't want to select that. How do I do that?

So far I have this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$packagepath\Scripts\" -Include *.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "o_dwh"
```

I tried this, but I know it's wrong:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$packagepath\Scripts\" -Include *.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "o_dwh" and "exec o_dwh" -notmatch
```

Comment: You can use a negative lookbehind, like this: `(?<!exec )o_dwh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work fine using a negative lookbehind `(?<!exec )` **to match only those `o_dwh` preceded by anything but `exec`** , a simple example:

```bash
# matches only last 2 lines

@'
something something exec o_dwh
exec o_dwh something
something o_dwh something
o_dwh something something
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Select-String '(?<!exec )o_dwh'
```

So, assuming this is what you needed, then the code would be (`-Filter` is preferable here instead of `-Include`):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path "$packagepath\Scripts" -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<!exec )o_dwh'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/VupVNA/1 for details.

Comment: Negative lookbehind didn't cross my mind! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This also solved my issue, but its not that elegant.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$packagepath\Scripts\" -Include *.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "o_dwh" | Where-Object line -NotMatch "exec o_dwh"
```

Comment: That's indeed another solution to the problem 